# Http request and Response is not working

Tags: networking, python

I am trying to use the simple Socket for Http connection but not able to send any request or getting any response.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
 Implements a simple HTTP/1.0 Server

"""

import socket


# Define socket host and port
SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 8000

# Create socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Listening on port %s ...' % SERVER_PORT)

while True:
    # Wait for client connections
    client_connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()

    # Get the client request
    request = client_connection.recv(1024).decode()
    print(request)

    # Send HTTP response
    response = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\nHello World'
    client_connection.sendall(response.encode())
    client_connection.close()

# Close socket
server_socket.close()
```

The result of above code is

```
btssim@ni12-926:~/Testing$ python test_server.py
Listening on port 8000 ...
```

The result of cat /etc/hosts is

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.68.196.88    NI12-926
#IP6#   NI12-9266

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Your server is listening on port 8000, but your `telnet` is trying to connect to port 80. Read `man telnet`.

Comment: `telnet` has it's own protocol, (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc0495 ) and is the wrong tool for looking at HTTP. Read `man nc lynx links curl`.